# Find view with given x/y coords in android

Tags: android

is it possible to find the View that is displayed at a given absolute x/y pixel coord?

Edit: I found a suitable Solution that works great:

```
private View findViewByCoord(float x, float y){
    TextView textView = null;
    int[] location = new int[2];
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    for(int reference : cardReference){
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(reference);
        textView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        width = textView.getWidth();
        height = textView.getHeight();
        if(location[0] <= x && x <= (location[0] + width) && location[1] <= y && y <= (location[1] + height)){
            Log.i("Test", "Card " + textView.getText() + " is pointed");
            return textView;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where cardReference is an array of integer to Resources (in my case 20 TextViews arranged in a 4 x 5 Matrix):

```
int[] cardReference = new int[]{R.id.card1_1, R.id.card1_2, R.id.card1_3, R.id.card1_4,
                              R.id.card2_1, R.id.card2_2, R.id.card2_3, R.id.card2_4,
                              R.id.card3_1, R.id.card3_2, R.id.card3_3, R.id.card3_4,
                              R.id.card4_1, R.id.card4_2, R.id.card4_3, R.id.card4_4,
                              R.id.card5_1, R.id.card5_2, R.id.card5_3, R.id.card5_4};
```

To speed up performance i would consider to use an array of TextViews then call findViewById() in every Loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One 'solution' would be to loop through the parent view's children and check the `getLeft()` and `getTop()` coordinates against the X and Y coordinates of your choice. If there is a match, you have your view.

I'd like to hear other alternatives though.

Edit: You'd also have to work out the height/width of the view too in relation to the left and top coordinates given to see if your coordinates are within that range.